# Lucene: Fuzzy Searching for multi-worded phrases

Tags: java, eclipse, search, lucene

I'm facing multiple issues when trying to search for a multi-worded phrase over Lucene.

First of all, this is how I'm indexing the data:

```
IndexWriterConfig luceneConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(new StandardAnalyzer());
Path path = Paths.get("C:/Users/i_l_g/Desktop/DBpedia/qls_labels-textfield");
Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(path);
IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(dir, luceneConfig);
while (rs.next()) {
            Document doc = new Document();
            doc.add(new Field("entity", rs.getString("entity"), TextField.TYPE_STORED));
            doc.add(new Field("label", rs.getString("label"), TextField.TYPE_STORED));
            writer.addDocument(doc);
        }
```

As you can probably tell, I'm simply extracting rows from a database and indexing them.

Now I'm trying to search for 2-worded phrases that are similar to my query, but the problem is that I'm getting all kinds of sentences. Below is the code which I'm using to search for a phrase:

```
StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();

String query = "jodie foster";

QueryParser parser = new QueryParser("label", analyzer);

parser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParser.Operator.AND);

Query q = parser.parse(query);
```

The problem here is that I'm getting stuff like **List of awards and nominations received by Jodie Foster**. Which means that sentences containing the search phrase are also being returned.

I'm also trying to obtain phrases similar to what I searched for. I found online that I need to perform a fuzzy search, and to do that I have to append the **~** symbol to the query. It's working on single words, but it's causing me problems when using it on the above query. I tried something like

```
String query = "\"jodie foster\"~";
```

and I set the minimum similarity to 0.1 in order to make sure that it's working

```
parser.setFuzzyMinSim(0.1f);
```

But I'm getting the exact same results I got from the first attempt ( without the fuzzy search )

I also tried adding the **~** in front of each word:

```
String query = "jodie~ foster~";
```

But this causes the program to search for phrases containing words similar to **jodie** AND **foster**, when what I really need is to find a **phrase** similar to the phrase **jodie foster** as a whole without taking it word by word.

My final question is : How do I perform a fuzzy search for an n-worded phrase and find similar matches while neglecting long sentences containing this phrase?

Comment: did you find the solution for this issue?